# WiX build failing in TFS but working locally

Tags: tfs, wix, wix3.7

We're using TFS Server 2010 for continuous integration, and also using WiX 3.7 for building. I'm having a problem with the build failing in TFS with the following error:

```
Unresolved reference to symbol 'Directory:DocumentationDirectory' in section 'Fragment:SharedFragment'.
```

Now the build works fine on my local machine, but fails in TFS. There is a DocumentationDirectory element in the script so I have no idea why TFS is failing. I've asked around the office and no one can help so I'm posting on StackOverflow.

Any ideas? Help greatly appreciated!

Mark

Comment: can you please post the wxs so that we can take a look?

Comment: Also, make sure you committed all your local changes to TFS, that is, your local build and server build run from the same sources. Make sure there's no typo in the element name when you reference it from another fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now found the cause of the problem: programmer stupidiy! I had another project in VS that was unloaded but being built by the TFS Server.